# how to utilize same list view for search and category queryset in django

Tags: python, django, database

I am trying to build functionality in my Django app in which we can get data with two methods:

1. Using Search
2. Selecting a Category

Since both of them require to get data from the dataset, I am wondering if there is a way I can utilize same ListView (not a CBV) to output data.

**urls.py**

```
path('datalist/<slug:category_slug>/' views.problemlist, name="problem_list_category"),
path('datalist/search/' views.problemlistbysearch, name="problem_list_search"),
```

**views.py**

```
def problemlist(request, category_slug):
    qs = DataModel.objects.get(category_slug=category_slug)
    return render(request,'list.html',{'qs':qs} )

def problemlistbysearch(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get('name')
        objlst = DataModel.objects.all()
        qs = objlst.filter(title__icontains=query)
        return render(request, 'search.html', {'qs':qs})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Function-based View (FBV)

You can let the urls point to the same view (`problem_list`) in the `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ⋮,
    path('datalist/search/', views.problemlist, name='problem_list_search'),
    path('datalist/<slug:category_slug>/', views.problemlist, name='problem_list_category'),
    # ⋮
]
```

Then in the view, we look if the `category_slug` is set, and if that is not the case, we look for the `?name=…` query string part:

```
def problemlist(request, category_slug=None):
    if category_slug is not None:
        qs = DataModel.objects.get(category_slug=category_slug)
    else:
        DataModel.objects.filter(title__icontains=request.GET.get('name'))
    return render(request,'list.html', {'qs':qs})
```

---

## Class-based View (CBV)

You can also work with a class-based view, in that case you can define a subclass of a `ListView` with:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ProblemListView(ListView):
    model = DataModel
    template_name = 'list.html'
    context_object_name = 'qs'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'category_slug' in self.kwargs:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(
                category_slug=self.kwargs['category_slug']
            )
        else:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(
                title__icontains=request.GET.get('name')
            )
```

then we again make two paths that will invoke the same view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ⋮,
    path('datalist/search/', views.ProblemListView.as_view(), name='problem_list_search'),
    path('datalist/<slug:category_slug>/', views.ProblemListView.as_view(), name='problem_list_category'),
    # ⋮
]
```